# How to implement a company-internal icon gallery

Tags: database, web-applications, icons, gallery

I love writing my own web-based applications, but don't want to succumb to the *not invented here syndrome.*  So before I go write this myself, I'm looking for solutions that either do this, or perhaps frameworks (like Django or Joomla, etc.) that give me a starting point fairly close to what I need.

My company produces software with a large variety of user interfaces.  We've decided to keep an **icon database** where one can search for icons by size, keyword, etc, track there they've been used so far, upload them, browse them, etc.

I've toyed with the idea of starting with an "image gallery" (Gallery, Coppermine, 4homepages, etc) but I was hoping for something that allows us to track **versions** of the icons, like we do for all our other source files, and I'm sure the attributes we track alongside each icon will expand over time, so it needs to be easily extensible.

So what do people suggest I use as a solution or starting point for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a [DAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_asset_management) system